# Integer hash function for concurrent map implementation golang

Tags: algorithm, go, hash, murmurhash

I am using concurrent map from this [repo](https://github.com/orcaman/concurrent-map) which only uses string as the key and it doesn't have any implementation for key as integer so I tried implementing it by just replacing all `string` into `int64` and modify the hashing function.

Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/TechGeeky/85eacd7c750f78fb9be1057c19534308) for that where key is integer. Below is how I am hashing `int64` keys. Is this the right way to hash an `int64` to get the right shard?

```
// GetShard returns shard under given key
func (m ConcurrentMap[V]) GetShard(key int64) *ConcurrentMapShared[V] {
    // I assume the hashing function of Go's map is good enough
    return m[key%int64(SHARD_COUNT)]
}
```

When I run this code I am getting - `panic: runtime error: index out of range [-7]` on my above return line in `GetShard` function.

Is there anything wrong in my hashing function implementation? Any example on what hashing algorithm to use here with my code will help me understand better.

Do I need to use `murmurhash3` here on the key and then do mod on that? If yes, any example will be appreciated.

**Update**

So I should change my above `GetShard` method to like this -

```
// GetShard returns shard under given key
func (m ConcurrentMap) GetShard(key int64) *ConcurrentMapShared {
    var h maphash.Hash
    // what is the seed value I should pass here?
    h.SetSeed(seed)
    binary.Write(&h, binary.LittleEndian, key)
    return m[h.Sum64()%uint64(SHARD_COUNT)]
}
```

Comment: int64 can be negative. you need to address that

Comment: You comment "I assume the hashing function of Go's map is good enough", but there's no go map in this code. `m[key%int64(SHARD_COUNT)]` is a slice lookup (which is why you get an index-out-of-range when your mod operation gives a negative result).

Comment: If you do a modulo operation to pick a shard, you risk uneven shards when the inputs are predictable. For example, if all your keys are multiples of 32 (where 32 is SHARD_COUNT from that repo), then you'll always use the same shard. Typically before doing the mod operation, you'd hash the key (perhaps with a random hash if you need to be immune from maliciously chosen input).

Comment: Unless you already know map contention is a bottleneck, you should first consider `map[int64]V` protected by a RWMutex, or `sync.Map` (if you write keys once and read many times or you have goroutines that access disjoint sets of keys).

Comment: I am writing and reading keys multiple times. It's a heavy read write for us both ways so that's why I was looking for concurrent map here. Do I need to use murmur hash here and then do mod on that?

Comment: Do not use any cryptographic hash: Slightly worse distribution fast is better. I'd give *(key+1)\*key%whatever* a try.

Answer (score 4):

You can check out for comparison [`puzpuzpuz/xsync`#`Map`](https://github.com/puzpuzpuz/xsync#map)

```
m := xsync.NewMapOf[int64]()
m.Store(1, "bar")
v, ok := m.Load(1)
```

Its [`hashUint64`](https://github.com/puzpuzpuz/xsync/blob/972e930347f61fa982841cdd8fa13ebe41453756/util_mapof.go) calculates a hash of `K` ([`IntegerConstraint`](https://github.com/puzpuzpuz/xsync/blob/972e930347f61fa982841cdd8fa13ebe41453756/mapof.go#L77-L81)) with the given seed.

```golang
// hashUint64 calculates a hash of v with the given seed.
//
//lint:ignore U1000 used in MapOf
func hashUint64[K IntegerConstraint](seed maphash.Seed, k K) uint64 {
    n := uint64(k)
    // Java's Long standard hash function.
    n = n ^ (n >> 32)
    nseed := *(*uint64)(unsafe.Pointer(&seed))
    // 64-bit variation of boost's hash_combine.
    nseed ^= n + 0x9e3779b97f4a7c15 + (nseed << 12) + (nseed >> 4)
    return nseed
}
```

Used by [`NewTypedMapOf[K comparable, V any](hasher func(maphash.Seed, K) uint64) *MapOf[K, V]`](https://github.com/puzpuzpuz/xsync/blob/b25732a6ae65ca3641914c1b33228a60d321ff08/mapof.go#L111-L118)

> Keys are hashed to uint64 using the `hasher` function.
> It is strongly recommended to use the [`hash/maphash` package](https://pkg.go.dev/hash/maphash) to implement hasher.
> See [example](https://github.com/puzpuzpuz/xsync/blob/main/example_test.go#L15-L36).

Comment: So I should just use `hashUint64` method to hash my integer keys before using mod on them in my `GetShard` method? Let me know if I understood it correctly.

Comment: I also updated my question to change my `GetShard` method. Let me know if that is the right way and that is what you meant. If yes, then what is the seed value I should pass in?

Comment: @john This is a good approach indeed. The seed value can come from [`hash/maphash#MakeSeed()`](https://pkg.go.dev/hash/maphash#MakeSeed), as seen [`xsync#newMapOfTable]`](https://github.com/puzpuzpuz/xsync/blob/b25732a6ae65ca3641914c1b33228a60d321ff08/mapof.go#L142-L154).

Comment: Yup I noticed that too they are using `MakeSeed()` method. So one more question I have is should I generate seed every time in `GetShard` method or generate once and use that every time in my `GetShard` method?

Comment: @john Once per map created should be enough. As seen in ["Fast thread-safe randomness in Go"](https://qqq.ninja/blog/post/fast-threadsafe-randomness-in-go/#using-a-mutex-locked-xorshift-generator).

Comment: So I declared globally this in my `cmap` implementation - `var seed = maphash.MakeSeed()` and my updated `GetShard` method is shown above already in the question. After that when I run my application, I don't get any `panic: runtime error` but the total count from this new map isn't matching with what I had with original `cmap` implementation. Do you think this has anything to do with the way I am calculating hash and shard?

Comment: My updated [cmap gist](https://gist.github.com/TechGeeky/6d1d1e4e5a0c8332e06586eedab05534). Let me know if you see anything wrong here but my new cmap implementation is showing very less total count compared to original cmap implementation.

Comment: @john "the total count from this new map isn't matching with what I had with original cmap implementation": But is it matching the actual number of elements you have added to the map?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249409/discussion-between-john-and-vonc).